# facebook fb.ui display

Tags: facebook, xfbml, serverfbml

i used to use `<fb:serverfbml>` and to parse it `FB.XFBML.parse()`.

when i switched to FB.ui, it is very effecient. but as far as i understand, for "apprequests" method, i have to display mode available: pop up or dialog(iframe)

pop up opens in a new browser window. diolog opens iframe window in the same window

so i need to know, if it is possible to render FB.ui result as a part of html, as i can do in `<fb:serverfbml>`

moguzalp

note: i do a work around doing an rendering FB.ui result in iframe that a create. but it seems not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use fb:serverFbml, Facebook has made it very clear they are phasing this technology out and are encouraging developers to re-write their applications as iframes. Facebook will continue to improve the FB.ui({method:'apprequests',...}) code.

One issue developers have raised about FB's on page solution for other FB.ui dialogs is the placement on the page. For pages that are more than a screenful, the dialog often appears in an illogical location. The Popup, if used correctly as part of a click event, will display for the majority of users.

I've also created a post illustrating the use of the new apprequests method
http://af-design.com/blog/2011/02/17/using-facebook-requests-to-promote-a-website/